# Delete object in array in Riot.js when i have multiple tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, riot.js

I try to delete an object from an array but I can't access the array for some reason. How can I get the array object in the delete_task function?

In task.tag.html

```
<task>
    <button onclick={opts.delete_task}>{ title }</button>
</task>
```

In tasklist.tag.html

```
<tasklist>
    <todo title="test" delete_task={delete_task}></todo>

    <script>
        this.delete_task = function () {
          for (var i = tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if (tasks[i].title === this.item.title) {
              tasks.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
        };

        this.tasks = [{title: "test"}]
     </script>
</tasklist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parent` word, according to the [nested loops approach](https://riot.js.org/guide/#loops)

And the `item` from the event, according to the [events handling](https://riot.js.org/guide/#event-handlers)

In the result you could have something like that:
https://jsfiddle.net/relaximus/q4t8e0sc/

Actually, as the click event is bubbling up, you can use `onclick` on the whole task tag, in this case you will not need to pass the delete handler as a function in the tag.

And just write

```
 onclick={ parent.deleteTask }
```